# Convert logical combinations from Reduce to a usable function

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, replacement, geometry

I'm working on a geometry problem and would like to create a function to create a triangle based on the logical constructs output by Reduce but cannot obtain all the constructs.  Here's the problem:

Given the vertices of a triangle $A=(p,q), B=(r,s), C=(u,v)$ obeying the constraints $2p+3r+4u=0$, $2q+3s+4v=0$ with the origin $O$ lying interior to the triangle, find $r$ such that $[OBC]=r[ABC]$.
  So using the Shoe-String Theorem, I set up expressions:

(u s - r v) == -r (p  s + r  v + u q - p  v - u  s - r  q) && 
 2 p + 3 r + 4 u == 0 && 2 q + 3 s + 4 v == 0 && u < 0  && 0 < r < 1 && 
 p > 0 && s < 0  && q > 0

and solve for $r$ using Reduce:

```
Clear[p, q, r, s, u, v]
mysol = Reduce[(u s - 
      r v) == -r (p  s + r  v + u q - p  v - u  s - r  q) && 
   2 p + 3 r + 4 u == 0 && 2 q + 3 s + 4 v == 0 && u < 0  && 
   0 < r < 1 && p > 0 && s < 0  && q > 0 , r, Reals]
```

This returns

```
((v <= 0 && s < 0 && u < -(1/6) && p == 1/3 (-1 - 6 u)) || (v > 0 && 
     s < -((4 v)/3) && u < -(1/6) && p == 1/3 (-1 - 6 u))) && 
 q == (-(1/3) p s (-2 p - 4 u) - s u + 1/3 s (-2 p - 4 u) u + 
   1/3 (-2 p - 4 u) v + 1/3 p (-2 p - 4 u) v - 
   1/9 (-2 p - 4 u)^2 v)/(-(1/9) (-2 p - 4 u)^2 + 
   1/3 (-2 p - 4 u) u) && r == 1/3 (-2 p - 4 u)
```

From this expression, I would like to create a function:

```
getTriangle[v_,s_,u_]
```

which first checks that v,s,u meet the constraints of Reduce, then proceeds to compute p,q,and r.

I can extract the expressions for $q$ and $r$ with the following code:

```
myq = q /. ToRules @@ Cases[mysol, q == qval__];
myr = r /. ToRules @@ Cases[mysol, r == rval__];
```

but I'm unable to obtain the expression for `p` using a similar construct as well as the constraints for `v,s,u` and was wondering if someone could help me with this?  As I would want to change the constraints, would like to programatically create the function rather than just manually extract the expressions by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the following. It has the traditional output of `Solve` when no solution exists.

```
ClearAll[getTriangle];
Apply[SetDelayed,
 Hold[getTriangle[v_, s_, u_], Solve["eq", {p, q, r}]] /. "eq" -> mysol
 ]
```

Triangle exists:

```
getTriangle[-1, -2, -1]
(*  {{p -> 5/3, q -> 5, r -> 2/9}}  *)
```

Triangle does not exist:

```
getTriangle[-1, -2, 1]
(*  {}  *)
```

Alternative definition:

```
Unevaluated[getTriangle[v_, s_, u_] := Solve[mysol, {p, q, r}]] /. 
 HoldPattern[mysol] -> mysol
```

Comment: . . .wow!  Always a pleasure working with you guys.  Thanks Michael.

Comment: Pardon me Michael, but I removed my vote for this because I think there is a better way, unless you can show me that my approach fails.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Already upvoted yours. :)  I can't believe I forgot about `BackSubsitution`.  I seem to recall that it may have been what I needed a year ago or so, but I'll never remember for what.  Hopefully Dominic will see your solution.  Solving once is certainly more efficient than solving each time.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Will try them out once I iron out a bug with my Mainpulate.   I'll create a different thread since it's independent of this one.

Answer (score 4):

If we change the parameters of [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) we can get this:

```
Reduce[(u s - r v) == -r (p s + r v + u q - p v - u s - r q) && 
  2 p + 3 r + 4 u == 0 && 2 q + 3 s + 4 v == 0 && u < 0 && 0 < r < 1 && p > 0 && 
  s < 0 && q > 0, {r, p, q}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

> ```
> (v <= 0 && s < 0 && u < -(1/6) && r == 2/9 && p == 1/3 (-1 - 6 u) && 
>    q == 1/2 (-3 s - 4 v)) || (v > 0 && s < -((4 v)/3) && u < -(1/6) && r == 2/9 && 
>    p == 1/3 (-1 - 6 u) && q == 1/2 (-3 s - 4 v))
> ```

From which we can make a direct definition, eliminating [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and producing solutions some two orders of magnitude faster than Michael's solution.

```
tri[v_, s_, u_ /; u < -1/6] :=
  {{p -> 1/3 (-1 - 6 u), q -> 1/2 (-3 s - 4 v), r -> 2/9}} /;
     (v <= 0 && s < 0) || (v > 0 && s < -((4 v)/3))

tri[_, _, _] = {};
```

Test:

```
res1 = Array[getTriangle, {11, 11, 11}, -5]; // RepeatedTiming
res2 = Array[tri, {11, 11, 11}, -5];         // RepeatedTiming
res1 === res2
```

> ```
> {0.74, Null}
>
> {0.00482, Null}
>
> True
> ```

---

Inspired by Michael's comment regarding `Solve`, here is another approach:

```
sol = Solve[(u s - r v) == -r (p s + r v + u q - p v - u s - r q) && 
     2 p + 3 r + 4 u == 0 && 2 q + 3 s + 4 v == 0 && u < 0 && 0 < r < 1 && p > 0 && 
     s < 0 && q > 0, {p, q, r}, Reals] // FullSimplify;

{p, q, r} /. sol[[1]];
Thread[%, ConditionalExpression];
MapAt[Apply[And], %, 2]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[{-(1/3) - 2 u, -((3 s)/2) - 2 v, 2/9},
>   (s < 0 && u < -(1/6) && v < 0) || (u < -(1/6) && v > 0 && 3 s + 4 v < 0)]
> ```

Comment: One could use `Solve` instead of `Reduce`, too. You get a solution in terms of `ConditionalExpression`/`Undefined`.  `Solve` is probably the first thing that should have been tried in the first place, since obtaining a solution is the goal.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great point!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the complete Manipulate code (without the most recent suggestion yet and the custom label code for the points removed too).  I couldn't use the built-in TriangleMeasurement function as it seems to have a bug: [Stack link to description of problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211654/trianglemeasurement-in-manipulate-failing)

Note the values $[OCB]$ and $r[ABC]$ are always equal for the range I'm plotting.  Pretty nice I think!  Thanks for helping me guys.
[image]

```
tArea[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{semi, ab, ac, bc},
   ab = EuclideanDistance[a, b];
   ac = EuclideanDistance[a, c];
   bc = EuclideanDistance[b, c];
   semi = (ab + ac + bc)/2;
   Sqrt[semi (semi - ab) (semi - ac) (semi - bc)]
   ];

uft = 0.3;
Clear[p, q, r, s, u, v];
ClearAll[getTriangle];
mysol = Reduce[(u s - 
       r v) == -r (p  s + r  v + u q - p  v - u  s - r  q) && 
    2 p + 3 r + 4 u == 0 && 2 q + 3 s + 4 v == 0 && u < 0  && 
    0 < r < 1 && p > 0 && s < 0  && q > 0 , r, Reals];
Apply[SetDelayed, 
  Hold[getTriangle[v_, s_, u_], NSolve["eq", {p, q, r}]] /. 
   "eq" -> mysol];

Manipulate[
 {p2, q2, r2} = {p, q, r} /. getTriangle[v2, s2, u2] // First;
 a = {p2, q2};
 b = {r2, s2};
 c = {u2, v2};
 o = {0, 0};
 myTriangle = {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Triangle@{a, b, c}};
 ocbArea = tArea[o, b, c];
 abcArea = tArea[a, b, c];
 text1 = Text[Style["[OCB]= " <> ToString@ocbArea, 16], {-3, 4}];
 text2 = Text[Style["r[ABC]= " <> ToString@(r2 abcArea), 16], {-3, 3}];
 Show[Graphics@{myTriangle, text1, text2, Line@{o, c}, Line@{o, b}, 
    Line@{o, a}}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> 
   5], {{v2, -1}, -0.1, -5}, {{s2, -1}, -0.1, -5}, {{u2, -1}, -0.3, \
-5}, TrackedSymbols :> True]
```