# TriangleMeasurement causing problem when used in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, geometry

On my Windows 10 machine, `Manipulate` with `TriangleMeasurement` locks up once I start changing the sliders. Even with `SynchronousUpdating -> False` and `ContinuousAction -> False` it still locks up. Code below draws a triangle and then uses `TriangleMeasurement` to compute the area. It locks up after several movements of sliders. I wonder if someone could confirm this is reproducible or perhaps I'm not setting up `Manipulate` correctly.

```
Manipulate[
  a = {1, 4};
  b = {1, s2};
  c = {u2, v2};
  o = {0, 0};
  myTriangle = {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Triangle@{a, b, c}};
  cobArea = TriangleMeasurement[{a, o, c}, "Area"];
  Show[
    Graphics @ 
      {myTriangle, Line @ {o, c}, Line @ {o, b}, Line @ {o, a}}, 
      Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 5], 
  {{v2, -1}, -0.1, -5}, 
  {{s2, -1}, -0.1, -5}, 
  {{u2, -1}, -0.3, -5}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> True, 
  SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
  ContinuousAction -> False]
```

Comment: What happens when you use `:=` ?

Comment: The :=TriangleMeasurement is working.  Would you know why I have to use the delay assignment here?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the delayed assignment. The reason the `Manipulate` is working when you use `cobArea :=` is because that value is never used, so the calculation involving `TriangleMeasurement` is never actually carried out. Instead, I think this might be related to the fact that, for some values of your parameters, your three points become collinear. This might make the EXPERIMENTAL [`TriangleMeasurement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangleMeasurement.html) function misbehave. Consider for instance: `u2 = -1.2` and `v2 = -4.8`.

Comment: Yes.  It does indeed fail when I use the value of cobArea with the statement text1=Text[cobArea,{-4,5}] and then use it in the Graphics statement.

Comment: I should point out it fails even when the  points are not colinear as the application I'm actually trying to use it prevents the points from being so and therefore no values of the controls make them colinear.

Comment: @Dominic from my understanding you need to use `SetDelayed` as you will end up `Set`ting in the value of the `myTriangle` function otherwise. This is not helpful for use in manipulates. Alternatively I could see use of the definition of `myTriangle` instead of `myTriangle` itself within the manipulate being beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

`b,c,o` must depend on the `Manipulate`- parameters!

Try (now with Module, changed Manipulate parameter range and changed PlotRange)

```
Module[
{a, b, c, o, myTriangle, cobArea},
a = {1, 4};
b[v2_, s2_, u2_] := {1, s2};
c[v2_, s2_, u2_] := {u2, v2};
o[v2_, s2_, u2_] := {0, 0};
Manipulate[
myTriangle = {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[],Triangle@{a, b[v2, s2, u2],c[v2, s2, u2]}};
cobArea =TriangleMeasurement[{a, o[v2, s2, u2], c[v2, s2, u2]}, "Area"];
Show[Graphics@{myTriangle, Line@{o[v2, s2, u2], c[v2, s2, u2]},Line@{o[v2, s2, u2], b[v2, s2, u2]}, Line@{o[v2, s2, u2], a}}, Axes -> True,PlotRange ->All], {{v2, -1}, -0.1, -5}, {{s2, -1}, -0.1, -5}, {{u2, -1}, -0.3,  -5}, TrackedSymbols :> True, SynchronousUpdating -> False,ContinuousAction -> False]
]
```

The options `TrackedSymbols\[RuleDelayed]True,SynchronousUpdating\[Rule]False,\ContinuousAction\[Rule]False` aren't necessary anymore.

Comment: That code seems to lock up as well.  I copied it into a new session in a blank notebook.  I did have to edit it slightly a backslash was inserted into the copy but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Dominic Strange! I modified my answer, now it runs on v12!

Comment: That does seem to work Ulrich.  Thanks for looking at this.  It is a bit much though to need to enclose the Manipulate in a Module that way and add the extra code you added, unlike anything I've ever done in the past.

Comment: @Dominic The main problem seem to be the parameters `myTriangle, cobArea` which are redefined in every step `Manipulate` is called(code without Module) . That's why `Module` or `DynamicModule`  are advisable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using V11.3, so I don't have `TriangleMeasurement`, which arrived in V12. However, the following code works well on V11.3 and I don't see why it wouldn't work just as well on V12.

```
With[{o = {0, 0}, a = {1, 4}},
  Manipulate[
    b = {1, s2};
    c = {u2, v2};
    Dynamic @
      Column[
        {Graphics[
           {{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Triangle @ {a, b, c}},
            Line /@ {{o, c}, {o, b}, {o, a}},,
            Text["a", Offset[{2, 4}, a]],
            Text["b", Offset[{5, 0}, b]],
            Text["c", Offset[{-5, 0}, c]]},
           Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 5, ImageSize -> Medium],
         Row[{"Area = ", Area[Triangle @ {a, b, c}]}]}],
    {{u2, -1}, -0.3, -5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{v2, -1}, -0.1, -5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{s2, -1}, -0.1, -5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    TrackedSymbols :> {v2, s2, u2}]]
```

[image: demo]